# SVN won't let me commit moved tree because of one file

Tags: svn

I've moved my entire web tree in SVN from 'www/' to 'public_html/' (so as to match my dev server), and that seemed to be ok:

```
$svn move www public_html
A         public_html
D         www/contact.php
[tons and tons of this for all my files and folders in www/, ending with]
D         www
```

...and now I am just trying to commit the newly-moved public_html/ so it will be locked in. When I do that, SVN slowly works its way through all my files then dies with:

```
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: File 'public_html/zzzz.txt' is out of date
svn: '/root/!svn/wrk/d1ab8d20-f948-4391-ba64-9b41569e2eae/lmiv/public_html/zzzz.txt' path not found
```

Note that "zzzz.txt" isn't there in public_html/ (and wasn't in www/ either). So I've tried these commands, to no avail:

```
$ svn cleanup 'public_html/zzzz.txt'
svn: 'public_html/zzzz.txt' does not exist
$ svn up 'public_html/zzzz.txt'
At revision 149.

$ svn del 'public_html/zzzz.txt'
D         public_html/zzzz.txt
$ svn ci  'public_html/zzzz.txt' -m ''
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: '/root/lmiv/public_html' path not found
```

(Note, no error on that last one, but it doesn't fix the problem.)

Bottom line, my goal is to be able to fully commit public_html/, so I just want to make zzzz.txt get out of the way! The file isn't not there now, I don't want it to come back-- *I don't need it or care about it in any way.* The only reason I'm even fussing with it is that it totally blocking me from checking in the whole public_html/ folder, which I want to get tucked into my repository.

Comment: If you have TortoiseSVN, can you just rename the folder using the repo-browser?

Comment: Don't have TortoiseSVN, I'm afraid. (...but isn't that just a front-end to typing SVN command line options?) BTW just updated/clarified my question to be clear that I don't care about zzzz.txt (which isn't even there, anyhow)... I just want to commit public_html/

Comment: It sounds like that one file is out of date, but you moved it before doing an update.  Can you revert the public_html folder back to www and perform an update before the svn move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These things are always difficult to figure out because there could be so many things going on.

Just remember that `svn status` is your friend. That will tell you exactly what Subversion thinks is going on with `zzzz.txt`. You might have to use the `--verbose` flag and make sure everything is in your working directory is at the same revision.

I also recommend that you do a `svn log` against the repository and not the working directory. Use the `--verbose` flag, so you can see the file history. This way, you can see what's going on with that `zzzz.txt` flag and why it's causing you so many problems.

All of this will help you diagnose the answer. It'll probably be something really simple that you overlooked.

If all else fails, undo the move, and do another status:

```
$ svn revert www
$ svn delete --force public_html
$ svn status --verbose
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried all of those things and they sort of worked but I wasn't confident in where I was left, so I ended up just doing a fresh, clean check-out and then manually copying over the few files that I knew had changes. A little frustrating to have to do this "nuclear" option. I'm left feeling like SVN is a powerful, robust tool... until it gets a pebble in its shoe, and then things fall apart and become nearly impossible to get back on track. :-\